# "Reedit" or "re edit", which one is the correct one?

Tags: prefixes

I saw many times both reedit and re edit refering to "edit again".

Which one should I write? Are both corrects?

Comment: Don't you mean, "Which one should I write?" (because they both would pronounced the same way)

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, *reedit* is the more correct of the two, because it is a single word and should not have a space in it.  Personally, though, I would not use either; *re-edit* is the only form that clearly marks it as a three-syllable word, with the *ee* not forming a digraph.

The top answer to a very similar question on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/should-the-prefix-re-be-added-to-a-word-with-or-without-a-hyphen) indicates that non-hyphenated versions of some "re-" words with double-e have become accepted, but that the hyphenated version is always accepted.

Comment: Some more good guidance can be found in [this Business Writing blog](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2012/04/re-elect-or-reelect-pre-existing-or-preexisting-.html).

Comment: Your answer makes the correct points. CMoS 7.85 says "... hyphenate only if doing so will aid readability". It is never wrong to hyphenate a prefix, but it doesn't really help readers very often. One situation when the safe practice is to (almost) routinely hyphenate is when the prefix ends and the root word begins in the same vowel. Even with that guideline, I don't bother with 'cooperate'. I certainly would with 're-edit'.